# Why does Carousel not accept Next.js Image?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, carousel, thumbnails, nextjs-image

We use `react-responsive-carousel` in our `Next.js` project. When we replaced `img` with `Image` to optimize thumbnail image size, thumbnails disappeared. Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's a [limitation of `react-responsive-carousel`](https://github.com/leandrowd/react-responsive-carousel/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md.):

> Note that it's not possible to get images rendered inside custom components. Carousel will find the thumbs if they are rendered as direct children of the carousel or if they are inside a div or another normal html element in a way that it's possible to access the children of these elements from the carousel.
> For performance reasons, it's not possible to get images inside custom components.

`next/image` is a wrapper around the `<img>` element, which means `Carousel` is not able to pick up the images for the thumbnails.

Comment: Would you suggest an other carousel tool for Next.js?